# Rails - call to engine_name seems to be ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to make an Engine that is isolated by two namespaces. That is, let say for example I'd like to make an Engine whose classes all live in:

```
Car::BMW
```

And thus, my models for example should be placed in:

```
app/models/car/bmw/
```

And my tables should be prefixed by for example:

```
car_bmw_
```

I tried to accomplish this by having this code in `lib/car/bmw/engine.rb`

```
module Car
  module BMW
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
      isolate_namespace Car::BMW # This will call: engine_name 'car_bmw'
    end
  end
end
```

With this code whenever I generate a model however, the model is placed in:

```
app/models/car
```

And the table is prefixed by:

```
car_
```

What am I doing wrong? The version of rails I am using is `4.0.0.beta1`

---

### **EDIT**

I found this method in `Rails::Generators::NamedBase`

```
def namespaced_path
  @namespaced_path ||= namespace.name.split("::").map {|m| m.underscore }[0]
end
```

Which, as you can see, takes only the first part of the namespace. Does anyone know why this is?

**Is this a bug in Rails or am I not supposed to have my classes doubly namespaced?**

---

This is a quick hack I resorted to, to fix the generators.

```
require 'rails/generators'

Rails::Generators::NamedBase.class_eval do
  protected
    def namespaced_class_path
      @namespaced_class_path ||= [namespaced_path.split('/')] + @class_path
    end

    def namespaced_path
      @namespaced_path ||= namespace.name.split("::").map {|m| m.underscore }.join('/')
    end

    def class_name
      ([file_name]).map!{ |m| m.camelize }.join('::')
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a class like this

```
module Car
  module BMW
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
      isolate_namespace Car::BMW # This will call: engine_name 'car_bmw'
      paths["app/models"] << "app/models/car/bmw"
    end
  end
end
```

would allow you to load models from the subdirectory you specified. I cannot say if this is going to influence the generating process, though.

There's a whole lot more configuration options, see e.g. [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html#label-Paths). Edit them to match your needs.

Comment: Thanks, but loading the models is already working 'out of the box'. It is really the generating process that is not working as I think it should.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would want that. If you want to share functionality between your `Car` engines, inheritance might not be the way. You could potentially have it inception-style, a BMW engine inside a Car engine if you really want that.

If `Car` is not a module you want to add functionality to and share across other submodules, then drop it.

If you want car engines like `Car::BMW` to share functionality then you can have it as an external dependency. All your car engines could require a `ActsAsACar` gem or something.

I'm still having a hard time figuring out why you'd want to have a double namespacing.

Comment: It isn't primarily about sharing functionality, but about avoiding name collisions in a large project. If you take a look at the source of Refinery for example you would see that most of their models are also doubly namespaced.

Comment: So all of this is only to avoid name collisions? I created an inhouse CMS Rails Engine that also has double namespacing whether it's for single table inheritance or concerns (active_support) but I wouldn't use command line generators for that. Is it simply for scaffolding purposes?

Comment: Yeah, that's indeed the main point. I could ofcourse also prefix class names, but that looked pretty silly to me if namespaces are available. Now, it seemed a bit weird to me, that it is possible to have a doubly namespaced Engine, but that generators don't work properly.

Comment: rails g model Foo::Bar::Gong works pretty good to me.. I get /app/models/foo/bar/gong.rb and even /app/models/foo/bar.rb since it didn't exists! But you're right, they took the approach of prefixing the class name. Same thing to me. So what's the problem again?